# for loop won't enter, not sure why

Tags: javascript, loops, slideshow

I am trying to make a moving image gallery where every 4 seconds the image scrolls across.

I link to the javascript correctly, I'm sure of it.

Here is the javascript, I would like to know what's wrong with it.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
image();

function image() {
  alert("Entered Function");

  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = none;
    alert("Entered Loop");
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(image, 4000);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT: The missing quotes around style.display = none is not the issue. I just forgot to add them back after testing the code.

Comment: Are you calling it before the elements are rendered? Are there elements with that class?

Comment: try `window.addEventListener('load', image)`

Comment: Possibly. Any idea how I can fix this then? New to javascript, sorry :P

Comment: What are the values of x and x.length when you debug in browser's debugger?

Comment: You would enter the loop if x was populated, which suggests that it's not.

Comment: console.log(x);
Add this line before the loop starts.

Comment: Try loading the script after the elements.

Comment: Show the HTML..

Comment: what is the DOM element represented by  'slideshow' ?

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: Am I wrong in saying slideIndex is defined out of scope of the image() function?

Comment: `x[i].style.display = none;` should be `x[i].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: who knows. As already stated please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is being, when the script is executed, the elements aren't present. I believe, you are executing the scripts way before the elements are loaded. There are two ways to handle this:

1. Use `onload` eventListener.
2. Load the scripts after the elements are loaded.

And moreover, there's an error in the code, if you check the console. The `= none;` is not right. It should be a string. Change the line to:

```
x[i].style.display = "none";
```

A snippet here demonstrates that it works if you load the script after the elements are loaded.

```html
<div class="slideshow">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slideshow">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slideshow">Slide 3</div>
<div class="slideshow">Slide 4</div>
<div class="slideshow">Slide 5</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
image();

function image() {
  alert("Entered Function");

  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    // Error here:
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    alert("Entered Loop");
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(image, 4000);
}
</script>
```

You can see that the above code is working as expected.

Comment: This basically fixed it. I added a script tag after creating the slideshow images and put the code in that and it now works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ThomasUpson Awesome! `:)` Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you set display property:

Change this `x[i].style.display = none;` to `x[i].style.display = 'none';`, otherwise you will get an error like `ReferenceError: none is not defined`, which prevents alert from firing:

```js
    var slideIndex = 0;
    image();

    function image() {
      alert("Entered Function");

      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'none';
        alert("Entered Loop");
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(image, 4000);
    }
```

```html
<div class='slideshow'></div>
<div class='slideshow'></div>
<div class='slideshow'></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue. I was just changing that to see if the syntax was different.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, if you run the snippet you can see the code works. Do you get any other errors in the console?